# SQL, iif excel cell is null then fill another excel cell

Tags: sql, jet, iif

I have the following part of my query within excel that is not working.

`iif(master.[Canada] is null or master.[USA] is null ,'USER','' ) as [Stackoverflow]`

Am I doing the nulls correctly?

The logic should

1) If there is No Canada or No Usa data, put "USER" in Stackoverflow column.

2) If either Canada OR USA has data then Stackoverflow should be empty.

Currently what Im getting:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|  Canada   |     USA      | Stackoverflow |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|           |              |               |
|           |              |               |
| 912796NZ8 |              |               |
|           |              |               |
|           | US912796NZ81 |               |
|           |              |               |
| 912796NZ8 | US912796NZ81 |               |
| 912796NZ8 | US912796NZ81 |               |
| 912796qd4 | US912796QD43 |               |
| 298785HB5 | US298785HB50 |               |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

What I am expecting:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|  Canada   |     USA      | Stackoverflow |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|           |              | USER          |
|           |              | USER          |
| 912796NZ8 |              |               |
|           |              | USER          |
|           | US912796NZ81 |               |
|           |              | USER          |
| 912796NZ8 | US912796NZ81 |               |
| 912796NZ8 | US912796NZ81 |               |
| 912796qd4 | US912796QD43 |               |
| 298785HB5 | US298785HB50 |               |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

After changing query to `iif(TRIM(master.[Camada]) = '' OR TRIM(master.[USA]) = '','USER', '') as [Stackoverflow]`

It does a good job except now I still have some canada and USA data that gives me `USER`.

```
+-----------+-----+---------------+
|  Canada   | USA | Stackoverflow |
+-----------+-----+---------------+
| 62941ZPA6 |     | USER          |
| 62943Z4R0 |     | USER          |
| 62945ZLQ1 |     | USER          |
| 62950ZZE5 |     | USER          |
| 75585RLK9 |     | USER          |
| 00433JAA3 |     | USER          |
| 13509PEV1 |     | USER          |
| 13509PEZ2 |     | USER          |
| 62931ZLX2 |     | USER          |
| 62941Z8M9 |     | USER          |
| 62941ZYK4 |     | USER          |
| 62942ZV42 |     | USER          |
| 62943Z6T4 |     | USER          |
| 62946Z6Y0 |     | USER          |
| 62947ZWC8 |     | USER          |
| 62948ZTJ6 |     | USER          |
| 62949ZE51 |     | USER          |
| 75585RLK9 |     | USER          |
| 75585RMB8 |     | USER          |
| 75585RMW2 |     | USER          |
+-----------+-----+---------------+
```

Should not have USER for these 20 records.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Parfait thanks ! Your `master.[Canada] = ''` worked, do you want to make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jet/ACE SQL dialect does support `IS NULL`. However, as your current results suggest, empty strings (`''`) are not the same as the `NULL` entity. This is especially true in Excel (a non-database application where empty cells may not default to `NULL`). In fact, you are actually assigning empty strings in the *falsepart* of your `IIF()` call where records without `'USER'` value in *[Stackoverflow]* will be empty string and not `NULL`.

Consider extending your `IIF` expressions to account for zero-length strings and assigning `NULL` to non-matches:

```
IIF((master.[Canada] IS NULL AND master.[USA] IS NULL) OR
    (master.[Canada] = '' AND master.[USA] IS NULL) OR
    (master.[Canada] IS NULL AND master.[USA] = '') OR
    (master.[Canada] = '' AND master.[USA] = ''), 'USER', NULL) As [Stackoverflow]
```

Even account for invisible whitespace by using `TRIM()`:

```
IIF((master.[Canada] IS NULL AND master.[USA] IS NULL) OR
    (TRIM(master.[Canada]) = '' AND master.[USA] IS NULL) OR
    (master.[Canada] IS NULL AND TRIM(master.[USA]) = '') OR
    (TRIM(master.[Canada]) = '' AND TRIM(master.[USA]) = ''), 'USER', NULL) As [Stackoverflow]
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, but right now I am getting the logic where both Canada ANDUSA contain '', but I also want to exclude 'USER' when one of them is ''. Which is weird because it seems like it worked sometimes, and not all the time. I'll try adding trim.

Comment: Hmmm... using `OR` as done above should check both columns if either is empty string. Please explain initial data, current result, desired result. Yes, try `TRIM` as suggested due to unseen whitespaces.

Comment: a Strange observation, having the `IS NULL` part actually doesnt help to much (4000 canada records where user is), but when I removed this I have only 20 canada records where user is.

Comment: Once again, all these conditions use `OR` operator so if records fall in *any* of them, `'USER'` is tagged. Removing unneeded conditions should not change result unless there were cases that followed its logic.

Comment: updated the question, its acting like both canada and usa is null then put user, when it should be either null then user.

Comment: Ah! Got it. I read your condition wrong: *If either Canada OR USA has data then Stackoverflow should be empty.* which really means *If Canada AND USA do not have data then Stackoverflow should show 'USER'.* So use `AND` instead with parentheses pairs joined by `OR`. See edit and notice the additional conditions.

Comment: Thanks! your the best!

Answer (score 1):

I think, Jet uses the `IsNull()` function instead of the `IS NULL` operator:

```
iif(IsNull(master.[Canada]) or IsNull(master.[USA]),'USER','' ) as [Stackoverflow]
```

Comment: JET/ACE does support `IS NULL`. [IsNull() is a VBA function](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html) which JET can interface to but with overhead.

Comment: thanks cha, the query does execute but does not give expected results :(

Comment: what result it produces and for what data? Can you post some examples?

Comment: I posted some sample data, hopefully that helps